# What am I, and what's the missing word?

Tags: poetry

### What am I, and therefore what is the missing word?:

I was one amongst thousands
but I was the lucky one;
I came through those doors and saw you.
Eyes glazed with contentment
from courses consumed,
yet a glint in the eye showed you dared to presume
a free treat, something sweet,
something only part known
that might satisfy your curiosity.

So when you saw me your eyes lit up,
with eagerness you picked me up,
and looked at me, with untold glee,
as you tore my body in two.

I shattered into pieces, more fragile than I thought,
and as I lay there broken, you tore away some more,
then you pulled out my heart, my purpose for being.
You examined it there, I had no chance of fleeing,
you were seeing,
the message of my soul.

Then, after giving up all that once was secret,
you picked up the pieces of my broken body,
one by one,
I couldn't run,
I endured,
as you devoured them all.

So now I'm dead.
A ghost of what I never did,
an echo of a life once lived.
Only my soul is still alive.
The message it brought only known of as lore,
but soon it will be discovered once more
in the heart of one of my brothers and sisters.
And, for the eaters, it will offer good `fill in the single word here`.

Answer (score 6):

You are a

> fortune cookie

and the missing word is

> luck

Comment: A little too easy then, perhaps? I enjoyed writing the poem anyway. The missing word isn't quite the one I was thinking of (it doesn't scan as nicely) - I was thinking of the same word as as found in the object itself

Comment: That was my initial thought (and even what I initially typed) but it seemed odd to have the same word in both parts.

Comment: Yeah, the only reason I took it out really is because it made the poem too obvious when I left it in - but it appears that wasn't enough to make it hard anyway :)

Comment: For riddles set in this type, it is considered more polite and standard to provide an explanation of each line, or at least combination of lines, in the riddle.